# How to convert a Contact to Partner user using apex code?

Tags: customer-portal, user

I converted a lead into contact which is taking from web-to-lead.

But i am struggling at converting the contact to portal user using the code.

please can any one provide the apex code for converting the contact to portal user. if not, I think so, I have to create a user using apex code and then put the contact ID in it, which is not best way.

please give me suggestions?

Thanks and regards
KS Kumaar

Answer (score 1):

There is no apex function to 'convert' a contact to partner contact, automatically creating the associated user.

Also you'll notice that if you click on 'Enable partner user' in the Contact screen on the Salesforce GUI, it will still take you to the new User screen (with some fields defaulted). So even SFDC follows a 2-step approach, which you will need to simulate in APEX.

So you need to stick to the solution of creating a user (with the right portal profile) and putting the ContactId in there.

E.g. assuming you have the Id of the contact as `contactId`:

```
//Create user
Profile portalProfile = [select Id from Profile where UserType = 'PowerPartner' limit 1];
User theUser = new User(
    Username = 'test123@test.com',
    ContactId = contactId,
    ProfileId = portalProfile.Id,
    Alias = 'test123',
    Email = 'test123@test.com',
    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
    LastName = 'McTesty',
    CommunityNickname = 'test123',
    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
);
insert(theUser);
```

Comment: Thank You Guy......but i have one doubt. please explain it.
I found a class called Site and a method with respect Site class is createPortalUser(user, accountId, password). Could you please explain about it?

Comment: That's right, but unfortunately: "This method is only valid when a site is associated with a Customer Portal."  It doesn't involve the 'Contact' object but is specifically created for Customer Portals.

Comment: so finally, we do not have any code for it. All we need to do is we can get an user by clicking on Enable portal user only?????????

Comment: yes there is code for it. I updated my answer to show.

Comment: I knew that we can add user by performing DML operation. Anyway thank you for your help. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Ah ok now I get your question :-) Indeed there is no method for doing a similar thing for partner portal / partner community.

Comment: Yeah....... i too got conclude now.