# How to use Opportunity.PartnerAccountId in a unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I want to create a unit test to test code that works with PartnerAccount information on Opportunity. However, no matter what I try, I can't get the PartnerAccountId to populate on an Opportunity object.

Initially I thought that creating an OpportunityPartner object should do the trick, but an answer below pointed out to instead focus on creating a partner account and a partner user, then use `System.RunAs` with the partner user to create the opportunity.

Much of the information online is pre-2015 and no longer applicable to current releases. [Reference documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) barely provides any guidance, making the road to a solution a minefield of wrong choices. Find my best attempt below.

Before you start: you'll need to enable partner relationship management in your `project-scratch-def.json`:

```
"settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
        "enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable": true,
        "enableEnablePRM": true
    }
}
```

I'm not the most experienced programmer in this field, so apologies for any errors or misconceptions in the code below. Feel free to correct! I have added comments with things I discovered along the way. Here is the (non-working) code:

```
private static User createUser(UserRole role, Profile prof) {  
    Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
    String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
    String uid = h.SubString(0,8);

    User newUser = new User(
        Alias = uid,
        Email = uid + '@test.com',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LastName = uid,
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        ProfileId = prof.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York',
        Username = uid + '@test.com'
    );

    if (role != null) {
        newUser.UserRoleId = role.Id;
    }

    return newUser;
}

@isTest static void TestPartnerAccountId() {
    User partnerAccountOwner;   // Needs ownerProfile, ownerRole
    User partnerUser;           // Needs partnerRole, partnerProfile, partnerRole(?)
    Account partnerAcct;        // Needs partnerAccountOwner
    Contact partnerCtct;        // Needs partnerAcct
    Account acct;
    Contact ctct;               // Needs acct
    Opportunity oppty;          // Needs to be created by partnerUser, needs acct, ctct

    User admin = [select Id from User where IsActive = true and Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'];

    // Use runAs() to ignore governor limits
    System.runAs(admin) {
        // Start by creating the user that owns the partner account. This user must have a role.
        Profile ownerProfile = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'Standard User'];

        // Create new owner role, because we cannot use existing roles on a scratch org.
        // See: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BvaQAE&title=cratch-orgs-hit-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-add-a-role-to-a-user-record-in-the-newly-created-org
        UserRole ownerRole = new UserRole(
            Name = 'TestOwnerRole',
            DeveloperName = 'TestOwnerRole',
            PortalType = 'None'
        );
        insert ownerRole;

        partnerAccountOwner = createUser(ownerRole, ownerProfile);
        insert partnerAccountOwner;
    }

    // Use runAs() to have the user with a role create the partner account
    System.runAs(partnerAccountOwner) {
        // Create the partner account
        partnerAcct = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Partner Account',
            OwnerId = partnerAccountOwner.Id,
        );
        insert partnerAcct;

        // Create a contact for the partner account
        partnerCtct = new Contact(
            AccountId = partnerAcct.Id,
            FirstName = 'TestPartner',
            LastName = 'PartnerContact'
        );
        insert partnerCtct;

        // Create new partner role, because we cannot use existing roles on a scratch org. Can't get this to work though.
        // UserRole partnerRole = new UserRole(
        //     // Name = 'TestPartnerRole', // Error: Cannot specify system-maintained portal role field
        //     // DeveloperName = 'TestPartnerRole', // Error: Cannot specify system-maintained portal role field
        //     PortalAccountId = acct.Id,
        //     PortalType = 'Partner' // field integrity exception: PortalType (Account is not enabled for this portal type)
        // );
        // insert partnerRole;

        Profile partnerProfile = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'Partner Community User' limit 1];

        // This user has to be created by a user with a role (admin typically hasn't)
        partnerUser = createUser(null, partnerProfile); // FIXME: probably needs partner role
        partnerUser.ContactId = partnerCtct.Id; // Assign ContactId to convert contact to a partner (see: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127591/how-to-convert-a-contact-to-partner-user-using-apex-code)
        insert partnerUser;

        // Create a regular account and contact
        acct = new Account(
            // isPartner = true, // Error: field is not writeable. Indicates whether the account has at least one contact enabled to use the org's partner portal
            Name = 'Test Account'
        );
        insert acct;

        ctct = new Contact(
            FirstName = 'Con',
            LastName = 'Tact1'
        );
        insert ctct;
    }

    // Use runAs to have the partnerUser create the Opportunity, so it will automatically become a partner opportunity
    System.runAs(partnerUser) {
        oppty = new Opportunity();
        oppty.Name = acct.Name + ' Opportunity';
        oppty.AccountId = acct.Id;
        oppty.StageName = '1 - Identify';
        oppty.Marketing_Process_Contact__c = ctct.Id;
        oppty.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2021, 1, 1);
        insert oppty;
    }

    List<Opportunity> opptys = [select OwnerId, PartnerAccountId from Opportunity where Id = :oppty.Id];

    System.assertEquals(partnerAcct.Id, opptys[0].PartnerAccountId);
}
```

The main thing seems to be a chicken and egg problem in creating the partner user. This user needs a partner role, which needs a partner account, which needs a contact of a user in a partner role. I can't seem to break this cycle and therefore keep going in circles.

So, how do I get PartnerAccountId to populate on the Opportunity object in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OpportunityPartner is directly related to this.  Per to the [Opportunity reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm),  the PartnerAccountId is

> ID of the partner account for the partner user that owns this
> opportunity. Available if Partner Relationship Management is enabled
> or if digital experiences is enabled and you have partner portal
> licenses.

Your test script needs to create a partner account and a partner user, then use `System.RunAs` with the partner user to create the opp.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, David! Would you happen to have a link to a recent code example that does this? All my attempts to create the partner user and account end in Salesforce errors (up to and including "Internal Salesforce Error"), and the only relevant example that I could find is this ancient [2012 forum question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000091RxIAI).